# Ruby routing when passing a parameter to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view, I am passing a parameter to a method in my controller.

The path looks like this:
    `/boats/:id/destroy_image?image_id=#`

I've read the Routing from Outside In guide, and it only skirts over this type of option briefly and haven't been able to figure out how to route this to the `boats#destroy_image` method properly.

Could someone please shed some light?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an item in rails, it is usually done this way

The URL would be:

```
:url => /boats/:boat_id/images/:id, :method => :delete
```

This is called in a view like so

```
= link_to "delete", boat_image_path(boat, image), :method => :delete
```

And it would be handled by the `destroy` action in the images controller.

Restful routes will reuse the same url and change the method - in the boat image example, you can use :get, :patch, or :delete to view, update, or delete, respectively.

This is probably enough to get you going.  Routes are a major part of rails - both in generating urls in views and matching requests to the controller#actions. Take some time to get familiar with rails routes and restful concepts.

Answer (score 0):

ok. So this is easy. You can add the route like this

```
get  '/boats/:id/destroy_image' => 'boats#destroy_image'
```

You can simply send that extra id in params.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the rails nested resources following the naming convention,

```
resources :boats do
  resources :images
end

<%= link_to 'Delete Image', [@boat, @image], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

This requests to the **images controller** by the rails way. sending the boat_id and the image id.

But, if you want to explicitly route that to the boats controller,

add a route in the boats controller as,

```
delete '/boats/:id' => 'boats#destroy_image', as: :destroy_image(image.id)
```

send the **image_id** through params,

then in the controller,

```
class BoatsController < ApplicationController


    def destroy_image
        @image = Image.find(params[:id])
        @boat = @image.boat //do anything you want with the boat object

        if @image.destroy
        else
            // *** ***//
        end

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to list_tasks_path(@task) }
            format.json { head :ok }
        end
    end

end
```

So, the route you have mentioned takes you to the destroy_image action in the boats controller, even if the route dos not contain image_id as query string, but we are sending it through params. That's the power of rails.